# Problem with printing shannon entropy for a sequence of numbers from standard input

Tags: java, arrays, loops, if-statement

I'm trying to print shannon entropy for a given sequence of numbers from standard input. Firstly, the user enters a number stored in integer variable "m" and then only numbers between [1,m] will be taken as the sequence from the standard input and then, the shannon entropy is calculated for that sequence. I'm able to get shannon entropy for m<=4. However, for m>4, the result for shannon entropy is displayed as NaN. can someone help? Here's my code-

```
int m = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int[] xi = new int[m + 1];
    int total = 0;
    while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
        int x = StdIn.readInt();
        if (x > 0 && x <= m) {
            xi[x] += 1;
            total++;
        }
    }
    double entropy = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
        double p = (double) xi[i] / total;
        double plog = p * (Math.log(p) / Math.log(2));
        entropy -= plog;
    }
    StdOut.printf("%.4f", entropy);
```

For standard input and output, I've used the[StdOut](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/javadoc/StdOut.html) and [StdIn](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/javadoc/StdIn.html) libraries, which were already installed in my IDE IntelliJ. Here's the download link which bundles all the standard libraries including StdOut and StdIn-
[stdlib.jar](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/stdlib.jar).

Comment: Have you stepped through the code or put in any logging? Have you printed out the data you've entered to see if it's what you expect? What data are you entering?

Comment: You can fix this problem yourself by debugging; for reference please read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/); which is referred in [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: As a hint: What happens when `xi[i]` is `0`? That's the case when you don't enter every number from 1 to m _at least_ once. `double p = (double) 0 / total` = 0.0 => `Math.log(p) = ?` ... I stop now playing debugger for you ;) But if you follow that path to the end you'll figure out why you get `NaN` (sometimes).

Comment: And as a new contributor – _Welcome to Stack Overflow_. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about what's on-topic in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In particular, your question is missing a specific example input for which you observe the undesired output `NaN`.

Comment: @DaveNewton i can't find exactly which part of my code isn't working well but i can say, when m>4, value for shannon entropy gets printed as NaN ("entropy" variable).

Comment: @IvoMori thanks. I edited my code for Math.log(p) exception when p=0. Its working now.

Comment: _I edited my code for Math.log(p) exception when p=0. Its working now._ – great. I recommend that you write up and give a short answer to your question yourself. After a 2 days wait-period you also will be able to accept your own answer. In that way, this question won't remain unanswered (continues to pop-up as unanswered in searches); and may then trick someone in giving an answer at a later date.

Comment: @DaveNewton the only problem with my code was, I didn't keep in mind the exception that would arise when log(p)=0. I took that into consideration and now the code works smoothly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight modification that needs to be done for the case when p=0, because in that case, log(p) is not defined. Here is the modified code-

```
double entropy = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
        if (xi[i] > 0) {
            double p = (double) xi[i] / (double) total;
            double plog = p * (Math.log(p) / Math.log(2));
            entropy -= plog;
        }
    }
```